# MongoDB: unable to find certificate

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, ssl-certificate

I made a script in Python3.9 that connects to MongoDB to find or insert informations.
When I run the script in the venv of PyCharm I have no problem but if I compile it in an app (Linux PopOs) I get this error:

[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:11##)

Can you please help me to solve this problem ?

**SOLVED**

Solution: [pyMongo]

import certifi

ca = certifi.where()

client = pymongo.MongoClient(url, tlsCAFile=ca)

Comment: Your linux variant must have the common CA root certificates installed. Check for relevant ways to install the root certificates / update them .

Comment: How can I do it ?